# Understanding delete in C++ with

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have following code snippet from a C++ book I am reading.

```
int* operator=(const int& rhs, int *x)
{
   int *tmpx=x              //line 1
   x = new int(2)           //line 2 
   delete tmpx;             //line 3
   return x;                //line 4                   
}
```

My doubt is that If I am deleting tmpx on line 3 which holds the address to memory location that x points to, and deleting will invalidate the memory address, So wouldn't it be wrong to return x which is pointing to memory address that was freed at line 3 ?

Comment: Each `delete` should basically have a matching `new`, why exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: You are missing line 2.

Comment: No, `x` points to the new array allocated in line 2, whereas in line 3, a different object is deleted that was passed to the function via `x` (but you removed line 2 now in your edit. Why?)

Comment: The code doesn't do more than `delete x; return new int(2);` Without any error check the code is only confusing and should be either reduced to what it does or extended to contain checks.

Comment: this is a rather weird implementation of a `operator=`. For one you dont use `rhs`, its not clear why it takes two parameters and actually `operator=` can only be implemented as member function.  If this is not used as a "dont do it" example i'd suggest you to find a different book

Comment: @harper yes it does -- if `new int` throws (which, granted, would be more probable with a class), your version leaves the original `x` dangling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's right. Because here you're assigning a new value to `x`.

```
x= new int(2);           //line 2
```

So now `tmpx` and `x` point to different places. `tmpx` points to the old `x`.

```
delete tmpx;             //line 3
```

Here you're deleting `tmpx`, which doesn't affect `x`, which is now pointing to the new position.

```
return x;                //line 4
```

You're returning the address of `x` that was returned by `new` in this function.